# wallaroo dependencies and static helper classes

Tags: c++, pointers, dependency-injection

I am experimenting with the [wallaroo](https://code.google.com/p/wallaroo/) dependency injection library to get rid of my global variables.
One issue I am having is how to make my static helpers work again. Simplified my code looked like that

```
// FooService.h
class FooService {
public:
    Foo* getSomeFoo(int x);
}

// BarUtils.h
class BarUtils {
public:
    static double calcSomething(int x, int a, int b);
}

// BarUtils.cpp
extern FooService* fooService;

double BarUtils::calcSomething(int x, int a, int b) {
    // need a Foo, so I call the globally available service
    Foo* foo = fooService->getSomeFoo(x);
    return doMagic(foo, a, b);
}
```

With wallaroo `fooService` no longer is global. How can I get it into the `BarUtils`? `BarUtils` is never being instanciated but has only static methods.

I am trying to give `calcSomething()` the `FooService` as a parameter but I'm failing because the `Collaborator` cannot be cast to a normal pointer.

If I pass the parameter the `Collaborator` itself it would be problematic in case I already have a normal pointer to something. I saw this case when in a service. There the pointer I would have to pass is the `this` pointer and I cannot cast it to a `Collaborator`.
Having the caller to get the `Foo` and give it to `calcSomething()` would also not be an option because the logic to get the object is not always that easy and would duplicate logic.

Has anyone experience in wallaroo how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a user of Wallaroo, but I have tried it in the past. As always I solve every problem with constructor injection. You will no longer ever need global variables and static methods.

The trick is to get rid of all globals and static, and replace them with a class. Then the IoC frameworks take care of creating instances of needed classes and to propagate dependencies (if A need a instance of B and you ask only for A, the framework generate also B automatically)

You just have a Instance of BarUtils wich reference FooService, this is easy to do with any IoC container, the Wallaroo solution would be:

```
#include "wallaroo/registered.h"

using namespace wallaroo;

class BarUtils: public Part
{
public:
    BarUtils( const string& color );
private:
    Collaborator< FooService> myFooService;
};
//other sintactic sugar to get FooService instanced.
```

Personally I don't like very much Wallaroo because of so much string processing (creating a Catalog as strings, all types are strings etc..) but Wallaroo allows to do certain things not possible with other IoCs. The main problem is that your case is really a simple case that with other frameworks is simple to do, Wallaroo my be overwhelming at first time if you never used Dependency Injection before.

The Collaborator class acts like a smart pointer so you can just call "->" on it and use it for calling methods on FooService.

Comment: wallaroo uses strings because that's the only way to do configuration driven wiring :-) Other C++ frameworks / libraries provide just compile time dependency injection (i.e. you can define your types just at compile time)

Comment: compile time is good. Since C++ is not C# adding runtime configuration add really more troubles, at this point another language is much better choice

Comment: If you're ok with compilation-time DI, fine: you can use other frameworks; on the other hand if you need configuration driven wiring [run-time!] in C++, wallaroo is your only choice.